# orders view adding items that shouldn't be there

Tags: mysql

For a mySQL assignment we are to create a view that contains the item_id, title, artist, unit_price, and order_qty for prints in a database that were ordered between 2014-01-01 and 2014-03-28.

```
CREATE VIEW orders_v AS
  SELECT items.item_id, title, artist, unit_price,
  order_qty
  FROM items, orderline, orders
  WHERE items.item_id = orderline.item_id
  AND orderline.order_id = orders.order_id
  AND orders.order_date like '2014-01%'
  OR orders.order_date like '2014-02%'
  GROUP BY items.item_id;
```

However, data is appearing in the view for items that are never ordered and I am unable to find out why.

In my tests, there should only be four orders that fall within the desired time period: order_id's 9, 10, 11, and 12.

```
order_id:  9, item_id: 100, order_qty: 3
order_id: 10, item_id: 450, order_qty: 6
order_id: 10, item_id: 600, order_qty: 8
order_id: 10, item_id: 200, order_qty: 4
order_id: 11, item_id: 700, order_qty: 2
order_id: 12, item_id: 300, order_qty: 4
```

But instead it's displaying items that aren't ever ordered such as item_id: 400, or items that are ordered outside of the time range.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

My code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/DcRxEr7j), if looking and testing with it would help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the following part between brackets:

```
  ( orders.order_date like '2014-01%'
    OR orders.order_date like '2014-02%'
  )
```

That is because `AND` has precedence over `OR`, and so without the brackets you are saying that either all previous conditions must be true, or the last one (on its own). This is not what you intended, as you want the previous conditions to always be true.

Secondly, since you are grouping the result by item, but don't sum the order quantities, you'll just get the order quantity of the first record that matches. This is probably not what you want. Just wrap a `sum()` around that:

```
select ... sum(order_qty)
```

Although matching dates with `LIKE` works, you should consider changing the way you compare dates as it is not maintainable for longer periods, and even more difficult for more precise ranges. Instead, use `BETWEEN`, where you can set the limits up to the day:

```
orders.order_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-28'
```

See [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e722f/1) that has the corrections. It returns this result set:

```
+---------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
| item_id |     title     |     artist       | unit_price | order_qty |
+---------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
|   100   | Under the Sun | Donald Arley     |     46.8   |    3      |
|   200   | Dark Lady     | Keith Morris     |    120.99  |    4      |
|   300   | Happy Days    | Andrea Reid      |     78     |    3      |
|   450   | The Hunt      | Walter Alford    |     39.99  |    6      |
|   600   | Rainbow Row   | Judy Ford        |     46     |    8      |
|   700   | Skies Above   | Alexander Wilson |     98     |    6      |
+---------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. I made the change, and everything is now correct except that it is not counting one of the orders for item_id number 700 that should be in the searched date range.

Comment: You did not provide the dates in your question's sample data, so I cannot verify. Could you add them?

Comment: The dates can be found in the link I provided at the very end, there are a good number of them, however, the relevant ones are

`order_id:  9, order_date: 2014-01-18
order_id:10, order_date: 2014-01-31
order_id:11, order_date: 2014-02-01
order_id:12, order_date:2014-02-27`

Comment: I added to my answer a reference to an SQL fiddle, where I put the corrected version of the view, and I see article 700 appearing in the output.

Comment: I see 700 appearing too, but if I manually look at the information, I'm seeing that there should be 6 orders for 700, not 2.

There are 2 orders for it in order_id 11, and then 4 for order_id 12, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: You're right, there was a `sum()` missing in your query. I have updated my answer. Now it returns 6 for article 700.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are your friends. `OR` has a higher precedence than `AND`, so you're getting a Cartesian product on all the orders in February. Your view should be defined as

```
CREATE VIEW orders_v AS
  SELECT items.item_id, title, artist, unit_price, order_qty
    FROM items, orderline, orders
    WHERE items.item_id = orderline.item_id
      AND orderline.order_id = orders.order_id
      AND (orders.order_date like '2014-01%'
       OR orders.order_date like '2014-02%')
    GROUP BY items.item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to improve your query.  First is to separate joins from where clauses using the [`JOIN` syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  This makes the query easier to read and can help spot problems.

```
SELECT items.item_id, title, artist, unit_price, order_qty
  FROM items
  JOIN orderline ON items.item_id = orderline.item_id
  JOIN orders    ON orderline.order_id = orders.order_id
  WHERE orders.order_date like '2014-01%'
     OR orders.order_date like '2014-02%'
  GROUP BY items.item_id
```

As pointed out in the other answers, this fixes your problem because there's no longer an AND/OR precedence issue.

Second is the unfortunate choice of using `CHAR(10)` to store dates.  Fortunately you're using ISO 8601 format so you can sort them easily, but it would be better to store them as [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) or `DATETIME` to take advantage of the full range of [MySQL's date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html), and date indexing, and using less storage space.  If `order_date` were a `DATE` you can write your query with [`BETWEEN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).

```
SELECT items.item_id, title, artist, unit_price, order_qty
  FROM items
  JOIN orderline ON items.item_id = orderline.item_id
  JOIN orders    ON orderline.order_id = orders.order_id
  WHERE orders.order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-28'
  GROUP BY items.item_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on how to improve my query. Unfortunately for whatever reason, the instructor wants us to use `CHAR(10)` for the dates, so that was why I went about things the way I did.

Comment: @Zach An instructor told you to do that? Oi. Get them on here and we'll set them straight. :)

Comment: I think the purpose behind it was to get us to think outside the box in how to handle a situation like this, because in the real world you may sometimes have a situation like this where you can't just change the data type :p But thank you, though, haha!